# What's the difference between a transaction manager and a database manager?

Tags: database, transactions

Reading on both it seems that they both have similar responsibilities of managing the sharing and integrity of resources as well as prioritizing execution but I cannot seem to find how they differ? Can someone clarify this misunderstanding. 
Thank You

Comment: Are you aware that you can have transactions in things that aren't generally called databases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what Oded already said:

A transaction manager manages transactions - and a transaction can include/address other resources than just databases.  I have given the example of a printer at some occasions before.

A database manager manages data - and not necessarily in a transactional way.  There is a very popular SQL system whose 1.0 version did not have commit/rollback, iow, did not offer transactional functionality and thus did not offer much of support for data integrity.

The distinction is mostly rather obtuse, however, because:

- a great many real-life transactions involve no other recoverable resources than just the database,
- in order to guarantee data consistency, DBMS's cannot avoid having to offer most if not all of the functionality of transactions.

Answer (score 3):

A transaction manager manages transactions - these can be distributed (i.e. involving several databases/systems).

A database manager deals with a single database - managing it on the disk, memory consumption, query parsing etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just to ensure understanding:

Transaction Manager deals with multiple levels of control and the physical database.

Database Manager deals with the direct access of the physical database.

I would also like to add to both of these answers that the transaction manager is also responsible to enforce ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, and Durability). I was pretty much confused as well.